# How to ORDER BY column_name counting the number of strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column_name has multiple id numbers with separated by comma. i want to ORDER it by number of string.

```
The Database is like this:
=========================

id  | user_ids
====|==========
1   | 23,345
----|-------------
2   | 3247345
----|------------
3   | 2,34,1,54
----|------------
4   | 222,5,56

I need Output like this:
=======================

id  | user_ids
====|==========
2   | 3247345
----|-------------
1   | 23,345
----|------------
4   | 222,5,56
----|------------
3   | 2,34,1,54
```

Comment: Actually your table design violates the normalisation rules and you should consider a redesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order your results by the number of comma's in a specific field with a query like the following:

```
select * from table order by length(user_ids)-length(replace(user_ids, ",", ""))) asc
```

The order by piece of the query will count all of the characters in the field and then subtract all of the characters not counting the commas. This leaves you with the number of commas.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do something like this

```
ORDER BY (LEN(col) - LEN(REPLACE(col,',',''))))
```